# Database not displaying column name jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am populating datatable from an array of object, below is the code

```
 $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "defaultContent": "-",
                    "targets": "_all"
                }],

                data: appArray,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "col2value" },
                    { "mData": "col3value" },
                    { "mData": "col4value" },
                    { "mData": "col5value" },
                    { "mData": "col6value" },
                    { "mData": "col7value" }
                ]
            } );
```

The above code gives me only data in my table without headers , how do I add table headers using datatable APIS?

Answer (score 0):

can you try passing columns instead of aoColumns as below.
for reference please check [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "defaultContent": "-",
                    "targets": "_all"
                }],

                data: appArray,
columns: [
                    { title: "col2value" },
                    { title: "col3value" },
                    { title: "col4value" },
                    { title: "col5value" },
                    { title: "col6value" },
                    { title: "col7value" }
                ]
 } );
```